# Paginate is not a function

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Compañeros ayudenme !! Quiero paginar los resultados de mi modelo Artist extraidos desde mongoDB pero aparece el siguiente error:

```
Artist.find(...).sort(...).paginate is not a function
```

Este es mi modelo

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ArtistSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  email: String,
  image: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Artist', ArtistSchema);
```

Esta es la función:

```
const mongoosePagination = require('mongoose-pagination');
const Artist = require('../models/artist');

function getArtists(req, res) {
  let page = 1;
  const itemsPerPage = 3;

    if (req.params.page) {
      page = req.params.page;
    }

    Artist.find().sort('name').paginate(page, itemsPerPage, (err, artists, total) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error in the request' });

      if (!artists) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'No artists' });

      return res.status(200).send({
        artists,
        totalItems: total,
      });
   });
}
```

Esta es la ruta:

```
const ArtistController = require('../controllers/artist');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/artists/:page?', ArtistController.getArtists);

module.exports = router;
```

Por favor ayúdenme !!

Comment: ¿Has comprobado de qué tipo es el objeto devuelto por `Artist.find(...).sort(...)`?

Comment: El sort funciona con un key y un value el key el campo y el value el ordenamiento ,debes hacer algo como .sort({"name":-1})